# How can I make MultiBit go one year back and then replay the blockchain?

Tags: multibit, balance

Like a year ago, I got a some bitcoins. I was using Bitcoin-Qt back then. Because reading the whole blockchain since then takes a lot of time, I got MultiBit, created a new wallet and imported my private keys from Bitcoin-Qt.

The problem is that MultiBit only goes back a few days (looks like one day before I created my wallet in MultiBit) to replay the blockchain. So the balance shown is wrong. The function "Reset Blockchain and Transactions" doesn't help.

How can I make it go one year back and then replay the blockchain? At least I think that's what I need, I just don't know how.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Thanks for the help. Yes, I have imported them all. I've just reset again. I see that MultiBit goes back to November 2013 and starts replaying the blockchain from there. But that's just too late. It should go back to January 2013 instead. I just double checked one of the receiving addresses on blockchain.info. The transaction took place on 16th of January 2013 and the money from that address hasn't been spent yet.

Comment: I think this question is an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If I understand correctly, the main question should be "After importing my private keys to MultiBit from Bitcoin-Qt the balance is shown wrong. How can I fix it?"

Comment: Have you imported all Bitcoin-Qt keys or only your main address? Bitcoin-Qt sends change to new addresses by default, so if you send any Bitcoins, some might be on a second address now.

Comment: Wre you able to solve your problem? Please share the solution with us so it may be useful to others with the same problem in the future!

Answer (score 1):

When you import private keys, you specify a replay date for each private key. This should be before the earliest transaction involving that address. In your case, it appears that this is not the case. (Or maybe you just need to reset again - their site says it might take [up to 3 resets](https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_support_balanceIsIncorrect.html) for the balance to be corrected.)

You should [reimport your private key](https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_importASingleKey.html) with the correct date specified to have the balance appear. Note that having your private key(s) in plaintext on your hard drive makes them an easier target for attackers. To be most secure, you should consider those keys [compromised](https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_support_balanceIsIncorrect.html) afterwards: [securely delete](http://www.howtogeek.com/72130/learn-how-to-securely-delete-files-in-windows/) the file when you're done with it, and transfer the coins to a new address and avoid using those old addresses again.

Another way of transferring the balance is to send it from your out-of-date Bitcoin-QT wallet to an address generated by MultiBit. I'm not sure if that's complicated, [the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_set_up_a_secure_offline_savings_wallet) makes it appear simple.

Comment: I did specify a date that predates all of the associated transactions before importing the keys for the first time. (I tried a few times.) It didn't help.

Comment: Is there seriously no other solution than moving everything to a new wallet? Because even *IF* their ridiculous 3 reset problem works, it happens again after 1 transaction or after restarting the program.